# how to draw 3D pie chart using core-plot in ipad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot

I have to draw 3D pie chart in ipad using core-plot API .how can i do it ?
Please advise .

Comment: CorePlot is a 2d engine. There is no way to draw 3d plots now.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot is 2-D only. You can create simulated 3-D effects on pie charts using shadows and/or an overlay fill. See the Plot Gallery example app for some samples.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [BNPieChart](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty). It is a openSouce.
**Code Sample**

```
BNPieChart *chart = [[[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Orange"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.2 withName:@"Fandango"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Blue"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Cerulean"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.3 withName:@"Green"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Yellow"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Pink"];
```

Reference for [Code](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=104)

Comment: Can we do through Core-plot only ?