# 3-D Pie Chart look

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I want to draw a pie chart with some thickness. I have generated simple 2D pie chart. is there any way to make it 3D using some concepts of CALayer and then rotating in some direction.

```
-(void)CreatePieChart
{

  graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];    
  //CPGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPGraphHostingView *)self.view;
  viewGraphHostingPie.hostedGraph=graph;

  CPPieChart *pieChart = [[CPPieChart alloc] init];
  pieChart.dataSource = self;
  pieChart.delegate = self;
  pieChart.pieRadius = 100.0;
  pieChart.identifier = @"PieChart1";
  pieChart.startAngle=0;

  pieChart.sliceDirection = CPPieDirectionCounterClockwise;

  NSMutableArray *ValueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  ValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:57.03],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:66.00],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:77.03],nil];
  self.pieData = ValueArray;

  CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPDarkGradientTheme];
  [graph applyTheme:theme];

  [graph addPlot:pieChart];
  [pieChart release];

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about - if you mean the edit I did  you'd missed out some of your code from the code block and it was harder to read. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: i want to create a piechart something like this:- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pie-chart-3d-free/id399375640?mt=8

Comment: Ok, I am about to say something off topic and not directly related to your question, but here goes: the only thing worse than a pie chart is a 3D pie chart. See for example http://www.quora.com/How-and-why-are-pie-charts-considered-evil-by-data-visualization-experts for discussion. (N.B. pie charts aren't always bad per se, but they are way overused, and often used inappropriately.)

Comment: so you want to say that we don't use pie chart to represent a firm data.

Comment: Not necessarily saying "just don't use pie charts"; just saying "Use a pie chart if it's appropriate and is better than, say, a bar chart" - but a lot of the time, a bar chart will serve as well, if not better, than a pie. Read the link I posted in my comment above to see discussion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to draw 3D pie chart using core-plot in ipad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977557/how-to-draw-3d-pie-chart-using-core-plot-in-ipad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "concepts of CALayer".

Have you considered using a free third party solution which will give you various charts, including pie charts, out of the box? [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is free.

**EDIT:** Core Plot is 2D only, but you can produce a 3D effect by using shadows and/or overlay fill. See also the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977557/how-to-draw-3d-pie-chart-using-core-plot-in-ipad).

Comment: coreplot is free i know but only generates 2D graphs if not customized. something of this type i want to generate itunes.apple.com/us/app/pie-chart-3d-free/id399375640?mt=8